# CORS - Duplicate cookie for multiple domains - set-cookie header is ignored by fetch

Tags: javascript, cookies, cross-domain, fetch-api

I want to share a user consent state on multiple domains. I tried to do it by sending multiple fetch requests, that contain the value as body. Each handler should simply accept the request and store the body as cookie-value.

Client-Side:

```js
fetch(data.handler, {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'cors',
    cache: 'no-cache',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'text/plain', // if we use application/json, a OPTIONS request (preflight) will be sent, that causes problems
    },
    redirect: 'follow',
    body: JSON.stringify(cookieValue),
}).then(response => {
    if (response.ok) {
        resolve();
    } else {
        reject();
    }
})
```

On the server side i send a response with a Set-Cookie Header

This is my response for the CORS domain:

```
curl 'http://localhost-domain2:8000/handler' -v -X POST \
  -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0' \
  -H 'Accept: */*' \
  -H 'Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.3' \
  -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate' \
  -H 'Referer: http://localhost-domain1:8000/' \
  -H 'Content-Type: text/plain' \
  -H 'Origin: http://localhost-domain:8000' \
  -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
  -H 'Pragma: no-cache' \
  -H 'Cache-Control: no-cache' \
  --data-raw '{"my":"values"}'
*   Trying 127.0.0.1:8000...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to localhost-domain2 (127.0.0.1) port 8000 (#0)
> POST /handler HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost-domain2:8000
> User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:103.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/103.0
> Accept: */*
> Accept-Language: de,en;q=0.7,en-US;q=0.3
> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
> Referer: http://localhost-domain1:8000/
> Content-Type: text/plain
> Origin: http://localhost-domain1:8000
> Connection: keep-alive
> Pragma: no-cache
> Cache-Control: no-cache
> Content-Length: 145
> 
* upload completely sent off: 145 out of 145 bytes
* Mark bundle as not supporting multiuse
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx/1.17.8
< Date: Tue, 02 Aug 2022 10:14:49 GMT
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< Set-Cookie: gdpr=%7B%22my%22%3A%22values%22%7D; expires=Wed, 02 Aug 2023 10:14:49 GMT; path=/; samesite=lax
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost-domain1:8000
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: User-Agent,Keep-Alive,Content-Type,Set-Cookie
< Content-Encoding: gzip
```

I masked some things like the json or the domain names, so some content-lengths will be wrong, but this is the actual response

The request is sent, the server does what it should but the Set-Cookie is not processed,  neither by chrome, nor by firefox. If i visit localhost-domain2:8000 no cookie exists.

So - what combination of fetch-parameters, HTTP Headers and Cookie-Parameters are required to make the client store the cookie for the other domain?

Edit: Just to clarify: I know i cant share cookies directly and i dont want to, i simply want the cookie to exist for the other domain, just like a single-sign-on

**Update**

Changing everything to ssl and using "None" for the sameSite Attribute does not change anything. Using Strict wont work neither.

**Update 2**

Opening the network request to the second domain from the dev-tools in a new window results in the cookie being correctly set, so its indeed the fetch api, that i have problems with.

Comment: I am using PHP, more in detail this package https://packagist.org/packages/hansott/psr7-cookies here is what it does https://github.com/hansott/psr7-cookies/blob/master/src/SetCookie.php#L167 According to https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.3.1 it should work.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE**

Okay, i was curious - it also works with fetch if i do everything else exactly the same as described below.

1. Setting of the Cookie exactly the same on client and server
2. Use the following fetch request

```js
fetch(url, {
    mode: "cors",
    credentials: "include",
    method: "get",
    cache: "no-cache",
    redirect: "follow",
})
```

The rest (Server-side, headers) like described below.

Firefox with cookie-protection still not working...

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

The following configuration works:

1. Insteadof using fetch to send a post request, i create an iframe with the src being set to the handler. The cookie-value is added as url parameter
   To resolve the promise i use iframe.onload and iframe.onerror
2. The Cookie ist set identically in the client and on the server.

javascript example:

```js
const secure = window.location.protocol.indexOf('https') > -1;
const sameSite = secure ? 'none' : 'lax';
// so in vanillaJs
document.cookie = 'key=value;' + (secure ? '; secure' : '') + '; sameSite=' + sameSite;
```

3. The domain field is kept empty for both sides (client, server) and the path is set to '/' in both cases, secure and sameSite are set the same way as on the client...
4. The HTTP Response from the Server contains the following headers (besides Set-Cookie)

```
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: ${HTTP_ORIGIN:-localhost-domain1}
Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate, no-store
Content-Type: text/html
pragma: no-cache
expires: 0
```

And an empty html5 document to avoid console errors

I dont know what really caused the issue, but this is how it works for the moment.

**Firefox**

This wont work in latest Firefox versions if Cookie Protection is enabled! It did not prompt me to allow the cookie usage, it just blocked it.

Edit: And it only seems to work via https